# What does .. mean in git commands?

Tags: git

I understand what `git cherrypick commitA..commitB` does; I've just seen that you can use .. in `git diff` too. I can't see why it's necessary there.

Does `..` have a consistent meaning?  What does `..master` mean in `git diff ..master`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+double+dots

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#_dotted_range_notations

Answer (score 1):

The related Git manual `man git-diff` says:

```
git diff [<options>] <commit> <commit> [--] [<path>...]
    This is to view the changes between two arbitrary <commit>.

git diff [<options>] <commit>..<commit> [--] [<path>...]
    This is synonymous to the previous form. If <commit> on one
    side is omitted, it will have the same effect as using HEAD
    instead.
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just to specify a range. I would verbally replace it with the word "to" as in, "commitA to commitB"